# String result to ExecutionResult using java in Neo4J programming

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

In my application, for Neo4j db, Team is using standalone instead of server. But team is provided with one jsp to view results in string format.

In JSP page, we are having one form to write the cypher query in textarea, and having button  to fire the request to server. after firing the request to server, test result will be printed in web page in the form of String.

Here, We need a kind of mechanism to convert printed string in web page to neo4j "ExecutionResult" Object.

Can some one provide the code snippet for conversion?

Comment: Can you explain more of what you are trying to achieve? You want to convert what string to an ExecutionResult?

Comment: Input String format follows below

+---------------------------------------------------+
| n                              | n.name           |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| Node[1]{name:"reference node"} | "reference node" |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row
0 ms

want to convert above string to "ExecutionResult"

org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult;

Comment: Why do you want to convert this into an ExecutionResult? This is the result of the query which is the ExecutionResult itself.

Comment: For my application, client is printing result string into web page, but i need reverse mechanism where i can convert "printed string into java object".

Answer (score 1):

You could simply send a JSON request from your web page back to the server, something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#log").append($("#query").html());
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/peterneubauer/WnPYp/ to grab the HTML element and send it with an AJAX request to the server?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reverse way, you would have to write a parser yourself.

But you could have the client not only have a textual result but at the same time a richer JSON result and/or a link to post that json to your site.

For some ideas look at the code for http://console.neo4j.org which is at http://github.com/neo4j-contrib/rabbithole

It converts the `ExecutionResult` into JSON and renders it as a jquery datatable in the client. And also has an additional popup (query details) for detailed data.